# Smith normal forms and a math program

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, modules, principal-ideal-domains

I am interested to know the Smith normal form of $4 \times 2$ matrices $M$:

The two cases of my interests are:

> (1). 
>   $$M_1=
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 3 & 0\\
> -5 & 4\\
> 4 & -5\\
> 0 & 3
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$

-

> (2). 
>   $$M_2=
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 2\\
> 1 & -2\\
> -2 & 1\\
> 2 & 1
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$

The goal is to write: a matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix}
m_{11} & m_{12}\\
m_{21} & m_{22}\\
m_{31} & m_{23}\\
m_{41} & m_{42}
\end{pmatrix}$

as

$$
M=VDW=\begin{pmatrix}
V_{11} & V_{12} & V_{13} & V_{14}\\
V_{21} & V_{22} & V_{23} & V_{24}\\
V_{31} & V_{23} & V_{33} & V_{34}\\
V_{41} & V_{42} & V_{43} & V_{44}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
d_{1} & 0\\
0 & d_{2}\\
0 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
w_{11} & w_{12}\\
w_{21} & w_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Here $V,D,W$ are integer matrices. And $\det(V)=\det(W)=1$.

Question: what is the V,D,W matrices for $M_1$ and $M_2$?

**Is there a math program one can use?** thanks~ :)

Comment: See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40923/has-mathematica-a-function-to-compute-the-smith-normal-form

Comment: @  Mariano Suárez-Alvarez thanks so much. let me see.

Comment: If you google "smith normal form mathematica" you get there. If you google "smith normal form maple", "smith normal form macaulay", "smith normal form gap" or "smith normal form sage", guess where you get to? :-)

Comment: Why did you ask on that site this again? That site is specific for Mathematica, and my link gives you the answer to your question as far as mathematica is concerned! I suggest you delete that question...

Comment: Ah, I will close it off. I think your link may already answer it. I thought you recommend me to ask there... sorry~ :(